# Import Task Group that contains Task Groups

Tags: tfs

When importing Task Groups from one TeamProject to another, if the Task Group contains other Task Groups (i.e. nested within the parent), then the import works but the links to the nested Task Groups are broken, and you have to remove them and re-add them. Importing the nested Task Groups first does not help at all.

I have had a go at editing the json to try to fix up the IDs,  but without success.

Has anyone found if it is possible to get this to work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, The Task Group works based on the existing tasks, if no such tasks in current team project, then the Task Group will not work.

The Task Groups are considered as special Tasks in TFS.

So, if you only import the Task Groups which have nested Task Groups, then it will not work, just as you mentioned the nested Task Groups are broken.

---

**UPDATE:**

Checked again, seems the Task ID of the imported  `Task Group ID is changed`, So the parent Task Group can not find the previous Task Groups...

So, import Task Groups which have nested Task Groups is not supported, unless you updated the Task Group IDs to match each other...

As a workaround, you need to remove the nested Task Groups first, then add them again.

Comment: Re: "You have to import all the nested Task Groups": I tried doing this first, then importing the parent (i.e. calling) Task Group, but it still does not fix it. Is it supposed to?

Comment: @TickFord Checked again, seems the Task ID of the imported  Task Group is changed, So the parent Task Group can not find the previous Tasks...